# VueJS & jQuery query selector

Tags: jquery, dom, vue.js

I am trying to get DOM element inside of .vue component, but i can`t bacause, as i think, the element have not rendered yet.

If i do something like this, it works:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $('.element').do_something();
}, 100);
```

But this is bad way.

I also tried to do something like this:

```
// app.js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    methods: {
        getElement(selector, cb()){
            var el = $(selector)                
            if(el.length){
                // I SEE THIS ELEMENT HERE
                cb(el);
            }else{
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.getElement(selector);
                }, 10);
            }
        };
    }
});



// ExampleComponent.vue
export default {
    created() {
        var el = app.getElement('.selector');
        console.log(el);
    }
}
```

But i got an error here:

> Uncaught TypeError: cb is not a function

I also tried to use Promise instead of simple callback.

```
// app.js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    methods: {
        getElement(selector, cb()){
            var el = $(selector);
            if(el.length){
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    // I SEE THIS ELEMENT HERE
                    console.log(el);

                    resolve(el);
                });
            }else{
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.getElement(selector);
                }, 10);
            }
        };
    }
});



// ExampleComponent.vue
export default {
    created() {
        app.getElement('.selector').then((el) => {
            console.log(el)
        });
    }
}
```

But getElement return undefined and i have an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Any suggestions how i can access element?

Comment: Where/when are you trying to get it? From within the Vue component? When in the event lifecycle?

Comment: yes, within vue component, in "created" method.
I have router, that load my component into <router-view>.
When this component loaded, i need to initialize jquery plugin on element inside of component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the root Vue instance the components and the HTML elements within them are not directly available and you do not have a chance to control your code to run after the components were properly created. I think that's a dead-end street. The other thing you mentioned is correct on high level. However your code doesn't seem right. The `export default created() {` bit is what bugging me.

Suppose you have a `.vue` file. Then it should look something like this:

```
<template>
  <!-- using refs is an easier way of getting elements -->
  <div ref="theElementYouWant"> ... </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data () {
    return {
      myvar: 0
    }
  },
  methods: { /* your methods here */ },
  created () {
    // using refs is an easier way of getting elements
    const e = this.$refs.theElementYouWant
    console.log(e)
  }
}
</script>
```

In case you really need jQuery you can import that as the first thing in the script part (`import JQuery from 'jquery'`) but you really don't need it for finding an element.

Comment: Yes, i have a .vue file component.
The problem was that i had v-if condition instead of i-show on my template body. And when jQuery tried to access element, v-if was rendering. But if i use v-show, element already rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Details:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/jquery-plugins-not-initialised-in-vuejs-when-loading-a-page-using-vue-router/16573

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-this-refs-return-empty-object/33227

Comment: Second one was useful. To sum up: if you're using v-if then the dom element doesn't exist. However, v-show solves this problem.